# How to delete fragment of line, which starts with "[" ends with "]" and all the characters (except [ and ] ) which are in the brackets? Perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $del1 = "[";
my $del2 = "]";
sub rings($){
    my ($line) = $_;
    my @lineArr = split(" ", $line);
    my $noSquareBrackets = $lineArr[0];
    $noSquareBrackets =~ s/[^$del1[^$del1$del2]*$del2$]//g;
    print "check: ", $noSquareBrackets, "\n";   
}
$/ = "\n>";
while(<>){
    /([^>]*)/;
    my $seq = $1;
    $seq =~s/\s//g;
    $seq = rings($seq);
}
```

The print before delete regex is exactly the same as before. And does any one notice, why  only one (first) file line is printed, when I have .inp format file with many lines?

The input file has such lines:

```
line 1) c1(ccc(cc1)N)S(=O)(=O)[O-].c1(ccc(cc1)C)[NH3+]  1519987
line 2) [Ce]123456([O]7[Cu]89[N](=Cc%10c7c([O]5CC)ccc%10)CC[N]8=Cc5cccc(c5[O]19)[O]2CC)(ON(=O)=[O]6)(ON(=[O]4)=O)[O]=N(=O)O3    1100946
```

I want to delete all data what is in square brackets with the brackets

Comment: You need to show a sample of your input data together with the corresponding expected output.

Comment: Try `s/\[[^\[\]]*\]//g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1: Why your program prints only 1 line

Note row `$/ = "\n>";` in your code.
It sets the content of **record separator** (what sequence of characters treat
as the end of input line).

As you can see, it contains a newline character, **followed by a `>`**.

And now look at your input. Nowhere after any newline there can be found any `>`.
The result is that your code reads **the whole input file** as the first
input row.

The possible solutions are:

- Add a `>` at the beginning of each line but the first.
- Delete `$/ = "\n>";` instruction, leaving the default record saparator
  as `"\n"`.

### Part 2: Regex

Remember that e.g. `[` and `]` in regex have special meaning.
If you want use them "literally", you must escape them with backslashes.

Another remark is that after "opening" `[` you should match a sequence
of chars different from `]` only.

So your regex to eliminate `[...]` should be:

```
s/\[[^\]]*\]//g
```